# Taking params[:id] into a .json file with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm currently using the Full Calendar gem for Rails, and all is working perfectly. However I would like to dynamically display calendar events based on the :id in the address bar via routes in Ruby on Rails.

Here's my index.json.jbuilder file

```
json.array!(@appointments.all.where(:user_id => params[:id])) do |appointment|
  json.extract! appointment, :id, :user_id, :business_title, :address
  json.user appointment.user_id
  json.title appointment.business_title
  json.start appointment.starts_at
  json.className 'boobs'
  json.end appointment.starts_at + 30.minutes
  json.url appointment_url(appointment, format: :html)
end
```

This works when the params[:id] is replaced with an existing user id from my database. The url thats generating this is localhost:3000/c/2, so this should display all the events that have been created/or belong to the user with the ID of 2. Here's my Routes:

```
get 'calendar/:id' => 'users#calendar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your calendar action, write:

```
@id = params[:id]
```

Then in your jbuilder file, write:

```
json.array!(@appointments.all.where(:user_id => @id)) do |appointment|
```

I guess that means, you have this in your calendar action:

```
@appointments = Appointment
```

...which makes me wonder: why aren't you doing the following in your calendar action:

```
@appointments = Appointment.all.where(:user_id => params[:id])
```

...and then in your jbuilder file:

```
json.array! @appointments do |appointment|
  ...
  ...
end
```

**Response to comment:**

Suppose you set up your controller like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def calendar
    @user_id = params[:user_id]  #route: get 'users/calendar/:user_id', to: 'users#calendar'

    #By default, render()'s calendar.html.erb
  end

  def feed
    @appointments = Appointment.all.where(user_id: @user_id) 

    #For the request: http://localhost:3000/users/feed.json, by
    #default render()'s /app/views/users/feed.json.jbuilder
  end
end
```

..then you request your calendar() action like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/calendar/2
```

The problem is: once your rails app is done responding to a request, all the variables inside an action are destroyed, so `@user_id`, which was assigned the value of `params[:user_id]`, i.e. 2, will be destroyed.  As a result, when your calendar sends a request to the feed() action here:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      events: '/users/feed.json'   //****HERE****

    })

});
</script>
```

...you won't be able to access @user_id inside the feed() action.

And, because the calendar was never given the user_id, the calendar cannot include it in the url when the calendar sends a request to `/users/feed.json`.

The *stateless* nature of the web has been a thorn in the side of developers for a long time, so they have invented ways to make data persist between requests using hidden form fields, cookies, sessions, local storage, databases, etc.

Rail's provides a very simple *sessions* mechanism, which you can use like this:

```
  #route: get 'users/calendar/:user_id', to: 'users#calendar'

  def calendar
    session[:user_id] = params[:user_id] #Store the value in the session hash.
  end

  def feed
    @appointments = Appointment.all.where(user_id: session[:user_id])  #Retrieve the value from the session hash.
  end
```

However, you should read about the [potential problems](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-guidelines) when using sessions.

Finally, as far as I can tell your jbuilder page responds with a lot of data that is irrelevant.  According to the [fullcalendar docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/), an Event only requires a `:title` and the start time `:starts_at`.  But, your jbuilder file provides additional data that is not even used by an Event:

```
:id 
:user_id 
:address
```

And, you actually provide the :user_id data twice, once here:

```
json.extract! appointment, :id, :user_id, :business_title, :address
```

and the second time aliased under a different name, `user`:

```
json.user appointment.user_id
```

It looks to me like, the following is all you need:

```
json.array! @appointments do |appointment|
  json.title appointment.business_title
  json.start appointment.starts_at
  json.className 'boobs'
  json.end appointment.starts_at + 30.minutes
  json.url appointment_url(appointment, format: :html)
end
```

...which produces json like this;

```
[
 {"title":"XYZ",
  "start":"2014-12-25T12:30:00.000Z",
  "className":"boobs",
  "end":"2014-12-25T13:00:00.000Z",
  "url":"http://localhost:3000/appointments/1.html"},

{"title":"ABC",
 "start":"2015-01-25T09:30:00.000Z",
 "className":"boobs",
 "end":"2015-01-25T10:00:00.000Z",
 "url":"http://localhost:3000/appointments/2.html"},

{"title":"TTT",
 "start":"2015-01-03T14:30:00.000Z",
 "className":"boobs",
 "end":"2015-01-03T15:00:00.000Z",
 "url":"http://localhost:3000/appointments/3.html"},

]
```

Comment: Thanks @7stud, but I tried your method first, but it's not working. The calendar appears on my User controller, and the file is calender.html.erb - Here's the code from my controller, and the .json file is now calling cal_apps but still no luck.

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner, Add the code from your action, and the calendar.html.erb file to your question.

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner, I think I know what is wrong.  See the additional text in my answer.